# Add Task in specified column

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I work on a simple Kanban Board, and I want to add a new task when I click the button in each column, but when I click any button it adds a task to only the first column, and I want it in each column if I clicked its button, so at first, I was select ul by querySelector but when selecting it with querySelectorAll it added task only in last column
Here's my code, Please review

HTML Code

```
 <h1>Kanban Board</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <h2>Not Started</h2>
      <ul class="tasks">
      </ul>
      <button class="btn" id="btn1">+ Add(1)</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <h2>In Progress</h2>
      <ul class="tasks">
      </ul>
      <button class="btn" id="btn">+ Add(2)</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <h2>Completed</h2>
      <ul class="tasks">
      </ul>
      <button class="btn" id="btn">+ Add(3)</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS Code

```
    * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    background-color: #009578;
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
    gap: 6rem;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 5rem;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    font-weight: normal;
    user-select: none;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 5rem;
    width: 80%;
}

.row,
.tasks {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 1rem;
}

.input-container {
    padding: 1rem;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 1rem;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);
}

.field {
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    border-radius: 0.4rem;
    outline: 0;
    border: 0;
}

.icon {
    height: 2rem;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.edit {
    color: #002d24;
}

.remove {
    color: red;
}

.btn {
    padding: 1rem;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    background-color: #00866d;
    color: #fff;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);
}

.btn:hover {
    background-color: #006854;
}
```

JavaScript Code

```
const btns = document.querySelectorAll("button");
const tasks = document.querySelector(".tasks");
const rows = document.querySelectorAll(".row");

// Add task
function addContent() {
    const newElement = document.createElement("li");
    newElement.className = "input-container";
    const input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "text";

    const content = `<input type="text" class="field" id="input">
  
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor"
    class="w-6 h-6 edit icon">
    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
    d="M16.862 4.487l1.687-1.688a1.875 1.875 0 112.652 2.652L6.832 19.82a4.5 4.5 0 01-1.897 1.13l-2.685.8.8-2.685a4.5 4.5 0 011.13-1.897L16.863 4.487zm0 0L19.5 7.125" />
    </svg>
  
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor"
    class="w-6 h-6 remove icon">
    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
    d="M14.74 9l-.346 9m-4.788 0L9.26 9m9.968-3.21c.342.052.682.107 1.022.166m-1.022-.165L18.16 19.673a2.25 2.25 0 01-2.244 2.077H8.084a2.25 2.25 0 01-2.244-2.077L4.772 5.79m14.456 0a48.108 48.108 0 00-3.478-.397m-12 .562c.34-.059.68-.114 1.022-.165m0 0a48.11 48.11 0 013.478-.397m7.5 0v-.916c0-1.18-.91-2.164-2.09-2.201a51.964 51.964 0 00-3.32 0c-1.18.037-2.09 1.022-2.09 2.201v.916m7.5 0a48.667 48.667 0 00-7.5 0" />
    </svg>
    `;

    newElement.innerHTML += content;
    tasks.appendChild(newElement);
}

// Event Listeners
btns.forEach((btn) => {
    btn.addEventListener("click", addContent.bind(this));
});
```

Comment: It will be helpful if you share your CSS as well, and also put everything into a StackOverflow snippet (the <> icon in the taskbar).  I copied your code above to a Fiddle and ran it, and the output doesn't resemble a table at all, so it's hard to reproduce or investigate your issue.

Comment: I provided full code snippets above

Answer (score 0):

`querySelector` only returns the first element matching the provided query.  So in this line `const tasks = document.querySelector(".tasks");`, you are always getting the `<ul>` item from the first row, and then always appending the new HTML to this same `<ul>`, no matter which button you click on.

Comment: I updated it but not working as expected as well

Comment: Well, you will need to provide your new updated code, describe what is still not working, and also please do include your CSS.

Comment: I provided updated code

Answer (score 0):

```
const tasks = document.querySelector(".tasks");
```

This returns the first HTML element with the class tasks (so your first `<ul>`).

You are always appending `newElement` to the first `<ul>` element.

Possible sollution:

```
function addContent(ev) {
    const newElement = document.createElement("li");

    // Do the stuff you want...

    const tasks = ev.target.parentElement;


    tasks.appendChild(newElement);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, functionality worked fine but still have a small issue
it's added a new task after the button, not before it

Comment: In that case, you could use tasks.insertBefore(newElement, ev.target).
See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore